# Мерцание меню при закрытии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу разобраться, почему происходит мерцание элементов меню при закрытии, на долю секунды меню становится видным перед самым закрытием

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger-menu');
const burgerMenu = document.querySelector('.header__menu');
const body = document.body;

burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  burger.classList.toggle('header__burger-menu_active');
  burgerMenu.classList.toggle('header__menu_active');
  body.classList.toggle('lock');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

body.lock {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ul-reset {
  list-style: none;
}

.btn-reset {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header__burger-menu {
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 30px;
  height: 23px;
  z-index: 110;
}

.header__burger-menu::before,
.header__burger-menu::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  transition: .2s ease-in;
}

.header__burger-menu::before {
  top: 0;
}

.header__burger-menu::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.header__burger-menu .header__burger-menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
}

.header__menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 420px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: opacity .2s linear, height .2s linear;
}

.header__menu-list-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}

.header__menu_active {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 768px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .2s linear, height .2s linear;
}

.header__burger-menu_active .header__burger-menu-line {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.header__burger-menu_active::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 11px;
}

.header__burger-menu_active::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 9px;
}

.header__menu_active .header__menu-list {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <button class="btn-reset header__burger-menu" aria-label="открыть меню">
        <span class="header__burger-menu-line"> </span>
      </button>
  <a class="logo" href="/">
    <img class="img-setting header__logo" src="img/header-logo.svg" alt="логотип">
  </a>
  <nav class="header__menu">
    <ul class="ul-reset header__menu-list">
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">О нас</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Проекты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Этапы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Отзывы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Контакты</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Само меню не мерцает. Там у Вас скролл, который меняется, так как Вы меняете высоту...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этом параметре было `overflow: auto;` сменил на `overflow: hidden;`
Добавил `@media screen and (max-height: 400px) and (orientation: landscape)` под мобильную версию.

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger-menu');
const burgerMenu = document.querySelector('.header__menu');
const body = document.body;

burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  burger.classList.toggle('header__burger-menu_active');
  burgerMenu.classList.toggle('header__menu_active');
  body.classList.toggle('lock');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

body.lock {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ul-reset {
  list-style: none;
}

.btn-reset {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header__burger-menu {
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 30px;
  height: 23px;
  z-index: 110;
}

.header__burger-menu::before,
.header__burger-menu::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  transition: .2s ease-in;
}

.header__burger-menu::before {
  top: 0;
}

.header__burger-menu::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.header__burger-menu .header__burger-menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
}

.header__menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 420px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  overflow: hidden; /* изменено */
  transition: opacity .2s linear, height .2s linear;
}

/* Под мобильные экраны в горизонтальном положении не выше 400px*/
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .header__menu {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}


.header__menu-list-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}

.header__menu_active {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 768px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .2s linear, height .2s linear;
}

.header__burger-menu_active .header__burger-menu-line {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.header__burger-menu_active::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 11px;
}

.header__burger-menu_active::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 9px;
}

.header__menu_active .header__menu-list {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <button class="btn-reset header__burger-menu" aria-label="открыть меню">
        <span class="header__burger-menu-line"> </span>
      </button>
  <a class="logo" href="/">
    <img class="img-setting header__logo" src="img/header-logo.svg" alt="логотип">
  </a>
  <nav class="header__menu">
    <ul class="ul-reset header__menu-list">
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">О нас</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Проекты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Этапы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Отзывы</a>
      </li>
      <li class="header__menu-list-item">
        <a class="link-reset menu-link header__menu-link" href="">Контакты</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: overflow: auto там нужно для того, чтобы при смене ориентации экрана устройства можно было проскролить меню вниз и увидеть все пункты. Соответсвенно, если использовать :hidden, то часть меню будет недоступна

Comment: Обновил снипет, добавил медиа запрос под смену ориентации экрана.

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но все это не то, дело не в этом. Посмотрите еще раз внимательно пример-при закрытии меню его пункты еще раз появляются, надо было убрать из активного класса flex-direction:column